# cannot import name 'html5lib' error while installing packages

Tags: python, python-3.6

While installing `mxnet` package I am getting the error :

> cannot import name 'html5lib'

& when I go for `html5lib` package installation I am getting the same error.

The full error message can be seen in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXucS.png).

I have installed python using Anaconda.

Comment: not working check the image link.

Comment: install it first by typing, `pip install htm5lib`

Comment: Not working, same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `conda update -f html5lib` which will try to update your `html5lib`. I also encountered this after installing something (`tensorflow`) through `conda` that had to downgrade `html5lib` and that broke everything for `pip`.

Comment: I had the same error for module `pydot` as well. `html5lib` seems to be reinstalled but the original error persists. Any ideas?

Comment: I am still not 100% sure what the right solution is... It seems that in any way I try - `conda install` or `pip install` - `tensorflow` will downgrade the `html5lib`. After such installation occurs, I need to manually update `html5lib`, which kind of sucks when wanting to cleanly share an environment with someone.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 10 fix with Anaconda

```
conda install -c anaconda html5lib
```

ref: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/html5lib