# pip cannot install module due to html5lib error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to set up a tensorflow environment in win7.
I followed the instructions [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) and I guess I have installed tensorflow.
I managed to run the small script in the previous link but only inside the console of Anaconda tensorflow environment. Since the windows' console is a bit primitive (to be polite) I would like to install Ipython.
The problem is I am getting an error when trying to use `pip`. For example:

```
pip install pyreadline
```

gives this

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "D:\Software\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 6, in 
>       from pip import main
>     File "D:\Software\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip__init__.py", line 28, in 
>       from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
>     File "D:\Software\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\vcs\subversion.py", line 9, in 
>       from pip.index import Link
>     File "D:\Software\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 33, in 
>       from pip._vendor import html5lib, requests, six
>   ImportError: cannot import name 'html5lib'

Using some instructions I also tried this one:

```
python -m pip install pyreadline
```

with the same output. *pyreadline* is considered prerequirement for *Ipython* I think. If my console is elevated or not does no difference.

Generally speaking it seems all modules' installation attempts produce the same message. Even: `pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade html5lib` does so.

My system is win7, python 3.6.2 and I installed *tensorflow* using the instruction for Anaconda.
From Anaconda Navigator I see html5lib as installed.
So, how can bypass this problem to be able to install new modules?

Edit:
I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46729667/cannot-import-name-html5lib-error-while-installing-packages) which had a similar to mine problem but although accepted as an answer there it didn't solve the problem.
`html5lib` seems to be reinstalled but other modules are not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution to my problem came as an answer to this (very similar) but also 4 years old [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46729667/cannot-import-name-html5lib-error-while-installing-packages).

The problem is that the solution for me that actually worked is not the accepted one, so I am providing the second answer as the solution to my problem.

Using:

```
conda install -c anaconda html5lib
```

seems to unravel the dependencies and make `pip` work again.
ref: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/html5lib